# Hive Server 2 error on python connect with hiveserver2

Tags: python, python-2.7, hadoop, hive, pyhive

I am using

Centos , Python2.7 , hive 2.1 ,Hadoop 2.7.2 ,pyHive

here is code

```
from pyhive import hive
from TCLIService.ttypes import TOperationState
cursor = hive.connect('localhost').cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM my_awesome_data LIMIT 10', async=True)

#status = cursor.poll().operationState
#while status in (TOperationState.INITIALIZED_STATE, TOperationState.RUNNI$
#    logs = cursor.fetch_logs()
#    for message in logs:
#        print message

# If needed, an asynchronous query can be cancelled at any time with:
# cursor.cancel()

# status = cursor.poll().operationState

#print cursor.fetchall()
```

when I run python /usr/local/py/test5.py in terminal its showing ....

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/py/test5.py", line 3, in <module>
cursor = hive.connect('localhost').cursor()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 63, in connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyhive/hive.py", line 104, in __init__
self._transport.open()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 80, in open
status, payload = self._recv_sasl_message()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/__init__.py", line 98, in _recv_sasl_message
header = read_all_compat(self._trans, 5)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift_sasl/six.py", line 31, in <lambda>
read_all_compat = lambda trans, sz: trans.readAll(sz)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TTransport.py", line 58, in readAll
chunk = self.read(sz - have)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/thrift/transport/TSocket.py", line 120, in read
message='TSocket read 0 bytes')
thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes
```

Hive server error log showing after this...

```
ERROR [HiveServer2-Handler-Pool: Thread-41]: server.TThreadPoolServer (:()) - Thrift error occur$
org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Missing version in readMessageBegin, old client?
    at    org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:228)
    at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:286)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Also I had tried [pyhs2](https://github.com/BradRuderman/pyhs2) getting same error

what was going wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing the same problem and I feel that this is something about the `thrift_sasl` package. Haven't come further yet, this is frustrating.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the server? `sudo server hbase-thrift restart `

Comment: The error message says `Missing version in readMessageBegin, old client?` -- maybe `thrift_sasl` uses an outdated protocol version for `thrift`? For me, thrift connection to `hbase` works fine, just `hive` does not. Can you confirm, @imran-hassan?

Comment: Check if your server and client are running with same version of hive thrift

Comment: yes agreed hbase works fine but hive server shoing same error when trying to connect hiveserver2 with python

Comment: Check if your server and client are running with same version of hive thrift 
@NirmalRam how can we check ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453288/hive-thrift-missing-version-in-readmessagebegin-old-client

Comment: sudo server hbase-thrift restart after this me facing this error 

 **socket.error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer**

Comment: @kpie i had already try this but not working

Comment: Did you try changing the `hive-site.xml` to enable `NOSASL` authentication and subsequently restarting the thrift server?

Comment: check if version in python2.7/site-packages thrift is same as that of server

Comment: @jbndlr yes enabled NOSASL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hava solved this error with these versions :

Centos 7 , Python2.7 , hive 2.1 ,Hadoop 2.7.3 and java java 1.7.0_91

using [impyla](https://github.com/cloudera/impyla)

its working for me.

Answer (score -1):

> thrift.transport.TTransport.TTransportException: TSocket read 0 bytes

I had the same problem and solved it by

1. Start hiveserver2 ([how to start hiveserver2](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Setting+up+HiveServer2#SettingUpHiveServer2-HowtoStart))
2. Modify your port. The default port is 10000 or you can change it to follow your hive_site.xml

Comment: Can you explain your answer? From the output in the question it looks like the server is running, or you would get an error like "connection refused", but not "0 bytes read". Also, what's wrong with default port 10000? Assuming your answer is correct, what value exactly should be changed to what?