# Connection refused for hive

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hive, thrift-protocol, denodo

I am trying to access hive from denodo platform, but I get the following error message

```
"Unable to establish connection: Could not open client transport with JDBC Uri: jdbc:hive2://hostname:portnumber: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect ".
```

It used to work with the same configuration before and has stopped working abruptly. On checking the hive.log file , this is what I found:

```
> ERROR [pool-3-thread-5]: server.TThreadPoolServer (TThreadPoolServer.java:run(294)) - Thrift error occurred during processing of message.
org.apache.thrift.protocol.TProtocolException: Missing version in readMessageBegin, old client?
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:228)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TUGIBasedProcessor.process(TUGIBasedProcessor.java:75)
    at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:285)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I restarted the services, Safemode was OFF for Namenode, the Firewall for our remote server is off and the JDBC drivers are properly configured.

I am unable to debug the log file, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you seen this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/35462685/7625684?

Comment: What Hive version? What JDBC version?